# Adding a custom font to a bar button item

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I am attempting to add custom font to a bar button item but I am getting this crash.

```
-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I'm pretty sure I have added the font correctly, it is in my info.plist and the custom font shows up in IB.

This is how I am setting the font:

```
 NSDictionary *barButtonAppearanceDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error?

This is how I am adding the font.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does issue persist if you will use `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]` instead custom one?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with my custom font. I changed the font name to @"HelveticaNeue-Medium" and the app ran fine and changed the font. So it has to do with how im implementing the custom font... not sure what I'm doing wrong with that though. @Azat

Comment: Since you provide no details about how you installed the font, added it to the Info.plist, and verified the real font name, no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom font to your application, here is a useful guide:

http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

You can use this tutorial to double-check your custom font.

Whatever the method you use to add a custom font, run the below code to check the name of the font as it is loaded in your app. It will list all the fonts that are available in your app.

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

Then, you can get the name of the font in the system.

I don't know how you add your custom font, but in general, the Regular font is loaded without Regular suffix.

So, replace

```
NSDictionary *barButtonAppearanceDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

with

```
NSDictionary *barButtonAppearanceDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Comment: Thanks, I am actually following that tutorial exactly and my custom font wont show up when I log the font names.....argh.

Comment: @Andy Font names rarely exactly match the filename. Scan the log output again for your font. One test, remove the font entry and run this code again and see if the output is any different.